# DynamoDBTypeConverted not working and returning java.lang.ClassCastException while fetching data

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb

In my Spring boot project, I am using the following custom converter for my DynamoDB model attribute:

```
public class LocalDateConverter implements DynamoDBTypeConverter<Long, LocalDate> {

    @Override
    public Long convert(LocalDate date) {
        return date == null ? null : date.toEpochDay();
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDate unconvert(final Long days) {
        return days == null ? null : LocalDate.ofEpochDay(days);
    }
    }
```

Here is my model attribute getter method:

```
 @DynamoDBRangeKey(attributeName = "dateTimestamp")
    @DynamoDBTypeConverted(converter = LocalDateConverter.class)
    public LocalDate getSortKey() {
        return priceCalendarIdentity != null ? priceCalendarIdentity.getSortKey() : null;
    }
```

But once I try to fecth my data, I get the folowing error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Long cannot be cast to class java.time.LocalDate (java.lang.Long and java.time.LocalDate are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at com.test.myapp.model.converter.LocalDateConverter.convert(LocalDateConverter.java:7) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.repository.query.AbstractDynamoDBQueryCriteria.getPropertyAttributeValue(AbstractDynamoDBQueryCriteria.java:484) ~[spring-data-dynamodb-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
    at org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.repository.query.AbstractDynamoDBQueryCriteria.createCollectionCondition(AbstractDynamoDBQueryCriteria.java:670) ~[spring-data-dynamodb-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
    at org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.repository.query.AbstractDynamoDBQueryCriteria.withPropertyBetween(AbstractDynamoDBQueryCriteria.java:409) ~[spring-data-dynamodb-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
    at org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.repository.query.AbstractDynamoDBQueryCreator.addCriteria(AbstractDynamoDBQueryCreator.java:111) ~[spring-data-dynamodb-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
    at org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.repository.query.AbstractDynamoDBQueryCreator.and(AbstractDynamoDBQueryCreator.java:150) ~[spring-data-dynamodb-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
    at org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.repository.query.AbstractDynamoDBQueryCreator.and(AbstractDynamoDBQueryCreator.java:42) ~[spring-data-dynamodb-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createCriteria(AbstractQueryCreator.java:122) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
```

Comment: I can't understand why someone downvoted without event saying why!! that's really unprofessional

Comment: that's the problem of stackoverflow unfortunately.

Comment: it looks like your unconvert process is wrong, use it like this ->  `LocalDate.ofEpochDay(Duration.ofMillis(epochMillis).toDays());`

Comment: @muhammedozbilici I don't think so, I am trying to uncovert to days and not Millis!

Comment: exception log is bit strange because it indicates `convert()` method and log says `Long cannot be cast to class java.time.LocalDate`, but `convert()` method is opposite, `LocalDate` to `Long`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to convert from String to LocalDate.

```
public class LocalDateConverter implements DynamoDBTypeConverter<String, LocalDate>
```

Also, it seems such a converter might already exist and you don't need to implement your own.

https://github.com/sijakubo/dynamo-db-spring-boot/blob/master/src/main/java/de/sja/model/converter/LocalDateConverter.java

Comment: Yeah I know that I can convert from String, but why converting from Long is not working?!